# Mint update manager not updating

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade

After running update manager these are the error messages I get...

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

Software manager has stopped working also

I am using Linux Mint Maya. What is wrong?

Comment: You have a broken package list. This can usually be repaired by manually inspecting the file, but I am not capable of explaining a general method to do this. Removing the file in the error message, waiting a bit and calling the update manager again might fix the problem.

Comment: Hi Thanks, fixed it.... There were 2 files in the list folder that were web pages, with that same file name.. (don't knot how they got there)..  once deleted all works fine :-)  THANKS.....

Comment: I can get a similar error by manually trashing one of the `/var/lib/apt/lists/*_i18n_Translation-en` files (on Debian9 here). The question is: May server problems yield HTML contents in these files without `apt` noticing it? If so, `apt` and friends should be made more robust, i.e. should get code to detect this. `apt-get clean` wasn't enough to get it clean again.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be removing all files in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Then run the manager again or `sudo apt-get update`.

Did the trick for me.

Answer (score -1):

In the terminal:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*


sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
```